# Unique classname using style modules in react

Tags: reactjs, styles, unique

I would like to know how to give a unique classname using style modules.
There is a film component. I want to insert this component into another component, but I can’t style it, since everyone has the same classname (for example - style_content__fFz+B).

```
const FirstSection = () => {
   const [films, setFilms] = useState(datajs)
  return (
    <section className={styles.grid_container}>
      {films.map((film) => {
         return <Film key={film.id} film={film}/>
      })}
    </section>
  )
}

const Film = ({film}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
         <div><button className={styles.button}>{film.genre}</button></div>
         <div className={styles.transformed_title}>
            <h3>{film.title}</h3>
            <p>{film.public}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In Film component I have styled with nth child.
But it is also applied in the NewFilms component

```
const NewFilms = () => {
const [newFilm] = useState({"id": 9, "title": "SWEENEY (2006)", "picture": "http://localhost:3000/img/9.jpg", "genre": "thriller", "public": "Feb 24,2016"})
  return (
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <Film film={newFilm}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tried to write a function

```
const Film = ({film}) => {
   const filmClass = (id) => {
      const x = styles + '.' + 'content_' + id;
      return x
   }
  return (
    <div className={filmClass(film.id)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular approach is to allow a component to take class names as a property:

```
import classNames from "classnames";

const Film = ({film, className}) => {
   const filmClass = (id) => {
      const x = styles + '.' + 'content_' + id;
      return x
   }
  return (
    <div className={classNames(filmClass(film.id), className)}
```

`classnames` is a library that helps you build a `className` string by, for example, ignoring `null` and `undefined` values, instead of stringifying them.

Then in your custom class name for a component, you can override any styles you want.